# Verifying the Transpose of a Linear Operator

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators

I have a linear operator $\Phi$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and have created another operator that I believe to be its adjoint (transpose) $\Phi^T$.

What is the most direct way to verify that my $\Phi^T$ is indeed correct without having access to the matrix representation of $\Phi$ or $\Phi^T$?

Answer (score 3):

Compute $(\Phi x, y)$ and $(x, \Phi^T y)$, they should be the same.

Comment: Oops, I mean not classical, just regular adjoint---just the direct transpose.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You're dealing with a real vector space so adjoint and transpose are the same.